# Certified Mapping Scientist, GIS/LIS – ASPRS

Tags: certification, gis-professional

I'm looking for a bit of a resume boost with a certification / professional recognition.

I'm aware of GISP, but I'm wondering if anyone has any input on the Certified Mapping Scientist, GIS/LIS from  ASPRS (CMS-GIS/LIS).

Apparently, my question might be too subjective and opinion based...however, half of my goal is to hear opinions about it since honestly a certification is only worthwhile if it is positively viewed by those in the industry.

https://www.asprs.org/certification-program/certified-mapping-scientist-gislis.html

Comment: Courting opinions in a Q&A format where opinions are unwanted isn't going to yield the upvotes needed to discuss this in [chat].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the test for it about 12 years ago. Things like "What is the idea temperature to store color film at?" caught my attention. It was very dated than and had very little GIS content. I picked up a list of certified professionals and checked their occupations and found around 90% were from academia. Most had been grandfathered in and the failure rate was very high.

I have a BA and MS in Geography, a GIS Analyst for 10 years, and spent an additional 4 years as a photogrammetrist / Cartographer for the defense department when I took the test, I failed miserably.  I know of 2 other people that tried and also failed.

I usually only see the GISP and Esri Tech Certs on applications. It may have changed but ASPRS knew it had problems then and did not say anything when they took my money. Do a lot of research before you take this one.